# What is the little blue line above the timeline called?

Tags: kdenlive

[image]i'm trying to find out what this thing is called,

it's the little blue line above the timeline, is there a name for it? what does it do? thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. I see a dark-teal-coloured bar at some time which is a selection, but I don't know if that's what you mean. Make a screenshot and mark the object of interest.

Comment: ok, how do i upload a picture in my post or comment? thanks

Comment: Click on "Edit" below the question and above the text input field there is a little picture, right next of the curly brackets, click on it.

Comment: ok i did it i think thank you.

Answer (score 0):

They call that a "zone" which is something like a selection of the timeline. The video you've linked already shows how it can be used.

I don't know why it's already there at the beginning of the video, it seems intentional and a very short Zone-bar is always there by default. That's maybe to remind the user of this feature but in any case is a strange decision in regard of user experience.

The manual indicates such a zone can also be set via the program monitor. [More in the manual.](https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Monitors#Creating_Zones_in_Project_Monitor)